# Sum value without summing the strikeout value

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to calculate the overall sum without strikeout value

```
invoice             values
--------------------------------
 VI                   320
 VI                   260
 VI                   72
 VI                   72
 -VI-                 -72-
```

Just imagine the last value with - symbol is the strikeout value
the total sum should be 724.

i tried doing like the following formula but it return 0 value

```
IF {Command.void_flg} = 0 THEN
Sum ({Command.Vessel_amt})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First  create a new formula `@Vessel amt`

```
if ({Command.void_flg}) = 0 THEN
     {Command.Vessel_amt}
else 0
```

Then create another formula `@Sum amt`.

```
 SUM({@Vessel amt})
```

Then drag `@Sum amt`to the place you want.